# How to implement CommonJ Work Manager with WebSphere?

Tags: java, websphere, threadpool, commonj

I have never implemented CommonJ Work Manager with WebSphere. Infact, i am not even familiar with this term. We have one schedular running currently which runs after specific time interval, it creates a job and handles the job to the ThreadPoolExecutor. Each job does certain common work.
The job scheduling has been done using **org.springframework.scheduling.quartz**, now i have been told to implement this thing using CommonJ Work Manager.
I did some amount of googling and found below link,
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fasyncbns%2Fconcepts%2Fcasb_workmgr.html

But found it little difficult to understand. Any explanation with example will be grateful.

Comment: Either the world doesn't have the answer or something wrong with my question.

Comment: Found a very useful link http://sanjsuya.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/asynchronousbean-was-spring-integration/

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930098/spring-commonj-workmanager-in-websphere> <br/> This is what worked for me. Excellent explanation..!!