# WebSphere work manager with Spring @Scheduled

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websphere, spring-scheduled, workmanagertaskexecutor

How to use the IBM WebSphere work manager together with the Spring `@Scheduled` annotation in my servlet?

Spring provides the [`WorkManagerTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/commonj/WorkManagerTaskExecutor.html). It allows to configure a work manager as described [in the WebSphere docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=framework-thread-management-spring) or in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21073991/395879). However I don't see a relation to the [`@Scheduled`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks) annotation and can't find any documentation how it works internally.

My goal is to configure scheduled tasks in a convenient way (as given by `@Scheduled`) but I need the task threads created by the scheduler to be managed by WebSphere.

**EDIT:** In the original question I confused `DefaultManagedTaskExecutor` with `WorkManagerTaskExecutor` as the latter is deprecated in favor of the first. Now I understand that `WorkManagerTaskExecutor` is Java EE 6 (and therefore required for our WebSphere 8.5 environment) whereas `DefaultManagedTaskExecutor` belongs to Java EE 7 and can indeed be configured for `@Scheduled` which is documented with the [`@EnableScheduling`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html) annotation.

Comment: You don't see the relation because there is none. It uses a `TaskScheduler` not a `TaskExecutor` (which is for `@ASync`). Now you can configure a `TaskScheduler` that internally uses a `TaskExecutor` as explained in the documentation you reference (to `@EnableScheduling` annotation).

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you mean that Spring documentation appears vague as to the relation between task executors that you configure and `@Scheduled`. Absent that sort of guarantee, you could verify observationally if scheduled tasks are running on WebSphere Application Server threads by printing the stack from one of your methods and confirming the presence of `com.ibm.ws.*` packages. One easy way to do that is,

```
new Exception("capturing the stack").printStackTrace(System.out);
```

Spring's `DefaultManagedTaskExecutor` is documented to rely on `java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutorService`, which requires Java EE 8 (or Jakarta EE) and ought to work with version 9 of WebSphere Application Server traditional. It should also work with WebSphere Application Server Liberty.

If you are on 8.5.5 or earlier, you would need the `WorkManagerTaskExecutor` (referenced in one of the docs that you linked) which is based on the CommonJ WorkManager.